# How to update in node.js with sqlite3 like the function findByIdAndUpdate on mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sqlite, sql-update

I want to do something like this:

```
async update(request, response){
  const { id } = request.params;
  const ovos = await connection('ovos').where('id', id);
  const ovo = await ovos.findByIdAndUpdate(request.params.id, request.body, {new: true});

  return ovo;
}
```

In a aplication with sqlite 3. I think it's clear what i want to do: Basicaly i want make a update funcion that select the table that i want to update by id and update them. whit new values give by the user.

the data in the 'ovos' table are: id; lote_id; id_gema; id_albumen; id_casca being (lote_id; id_gema; id_albumen; id_casca) foreig keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is always an update rather than an upsert, you can just UPDATE like this:

```js
let data = [lote_id, id_gema, id_albumen, id_casca, id];
let sql = `UPDATE ovos
            SET lote_id = ?,
            id_gema = ?,
            id_albumen = ?,
            id_casca = ?
            WHERE id = ?`;

db.run(sql, data, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log(`Rows updated: ${this.changes}`); // should be 1
});
```

Use the `?` placeholders with the data in an array to avoid SQL injection - note the order of the array is important, so you may need to rearrange the way your `request.params` are structured.